# Why is my returned ajax call giving me two datapicker input boxes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have I’m doing an ajax call and the retured data is in a div container. The call is made when the user selects a date from the datepicker.  When the data is returned it I have two datapacekers’s input box on the form.  I only want one on the form.  Why is my returned ajax call giving me two datapicker input boxes?

This is a partial view that the data is being displayed in.  Here’s the script which I’ve tried putting to the top and bottom of the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datep").datepicker({ 
            showOn: "both", 
            buttonText: "Select Date",
            changeMonth: true, 
            changeYear: true, 
            yearRange: "-2:+2", 
            showOtherMonths: true, 
            onSelect: function (date, datepickder) {
                var sltdDate = { selectedDate: date };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Schedule/GetSchedule",
                    data: sltdDate,
                    datatype: "html",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#returnedData").html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
     });
 </script>

 <div id="returnedData">

     @if (Model.Assignments != null) {
        //table header here

        @foreach (var item in Model.Assignments.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i })) {
            // @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data)
            //More item data here    
        }
    }
</div>

<div class ="ui-widget" >
    <label for ="datep">Date: </label><input id="datep" />
</div>
```

Comment: UPDATE:

I wrapped the datepicker input box in a div then in the success function I removed the input box like this:

 $("#dateContainer").remove();

Now the second input box is gone but the one that's left does not respond to the onSelect function.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned ajax call put another date input field to the container that held the returned data.  I solved it by adding   $("#returnedData #dateContainer").remove(); to the success function.